# Establishing the congruences used for the Miller-Rabin primality test

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am supposed to show the following:

> Let $p>1$ be an integer and write $p−1=2^{k}m$ where $m$ is odd. If for all $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$, we have
>
> $$\begin{align}
> && a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{\!p} &\\
> \text{or } && a^{2^{r}m} \equiv -1 \pmod{\!p} & \text{, for }0 \leq r < k \text{,}\\
> \end{align}$$
>
> then $p$ is prime.

I've tried taking the contrapositive of Fermat's little theorem on the second congruence, but that doesn't seem to grant anything useful. The second congruence seems to grant something along the lines of $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{\!p}$. I'm pretty much at a loss.

Comment: Note the use of \pmod in my edit.  (And if you do the same with a multi-digit number rather than something requiring just one character, then you need braces, thus: a\equiv b\pmod{12} yields $a\equiv b\pmod{12}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I don't think you have stated the required condition quite correctly. Miller-Rabin requires: $$\begin{align} a^m &\equiv 1 \bmod p \text{ , or} \\ a^{2^rm} &\equiv -1 \bmod p \quad \text{ for some value of }r, 0\le r < k \end{align}$$

Comment: Clearly the conditions stated are not met for composite $p$ when $a$ is not coprime to $p$, in any case.

Comment: @Joffan im not sure why this is clear.

Comment: @SuddenlyNotHorrific $\gcd(a,p)>1$ is always a factor of $a^k$, so $ a^k \not\equiv 1 \bmod p$

Comment: @Joffan So: assume, $p$ composite, and take $a$ such that $gcd(a,p)=d>1$, then we notice that $gcd(a,p)=gcd(a^m,p)$, then from bezouts identity we have $d=a^mx+py$ which implies $d \equiv a^m\pmod{p}$, which contradicts the first congruence in the assumption. Which means $p$ prime.

Comment: The congruences listed are alternatives, however - to show a contradiction you need to break both of them. Fortunately this is easy,  since $a^k \equiv -1 \implies a^{2k} \equiv 1$ always, so they all imply that some $n>1$ exists with $a^n\equiv1$, which cannot be if $\gcd(a,p)>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Miller-Rabin tests for the property of odd prime $p$ that: $$\begin{align} a^m &\equiv 1 \bmod p \text{ , or} \\ a^{2^rm} &\equiv -1 \bmod p \quad \text{ for some value of }r, 0\le r \lt k \end{align}$$

for all $a \in (0,p)$.

This holds because $a^{2^km} \equiv 1$ by Fermat's little therorem, and because $1$ has exactly 2 quadratic roots, $\pm1, \bmod p$.

This latter property can be shown by considering a primitive root, $g$, modulo $p$. We know that every quadratic residue $\not \equiv 0$ has at least 2 roots since $b^2 \equiv (-b)^2$ and $b \not \equiv -b$. The even powers of $g$ up to $g^{p-1}$ give $\frac{p-1}{2}$ distinct values that are all quadratic residues, so every such quadratic residue has exactly two roots.

If however the number under test, say $t$, is not prime, then neither of these is automatically true (eg. $21^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 55$). Certainly when $\gcd(a,t) >1$, this value is always a factor of $a^k$, so $ a^k \not\equiv \pm1 \bmod t$ for any $k$ including the tested values. Although Miller-Rabin does not rely on stumbling across values of $a$ coprime to $t$, this is sufficient to answer your question.